# How to filter results of adding related work items

Tags: azure-devops

When adding a link from one work item to another and searching by title is there a way to filter the results to a specific project? We have two projects in our collection that have work items with identical titles so the search results shows the work items from both projects without any way to distinguish them other than ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the search keyword "proj". For example "proj:some_project some_work_item_title"

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)